# How To Chain on mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need a simple solution for chaining Conditions but I end always with errors:

If its not the remote address 123.123.123.123
AND its http host ex.example.com
GOTO example.example.com

I came up with this (which doesn't work):

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$ [C]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://example.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I thought the [C] flag can manage this but it doesn't. I didn't found any examples on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by chaining you mean that a `RewriteCond` depends on a previous one, you don't need `[C]`.

They're already connected by an implicit `AND`. So the following would suffice:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.123.123.123
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =ex.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://example.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note the use of `%{SERVER_NAME}` instead of `%{HTTP_HOST}`.

If your default virtual host accepts all incoming requests, it is *not safe* to rely on `HTTP_HOST`, since its value is taken from the HTTP header field `Host:` which can be forged!

Comment: Thanks, this works. If I need another IP Adresse should I just add another line between first and second and add an [OR] Flag after the first one?

Comment: Note: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)` is completely redundant.  Just use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%1`.

Comment: Indeed, Denis. Why don't you go ahead and edit my answer.